# How to wait for multiple QNetwork replies synchronously using QEventLoop?

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

My function downloads multiple files concurrently, using QNetworkAccessManager. And then it should wait for all the QNetworkReply replies to finish before continuing with the rest of the code.

However I can't get QEventLoop to work with multiple connections, it either returns before all the replies finish, or just gets stuck in what I assume is an infinite loop.

This is my code:

```
void DownloadFiles(QStringList urls)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QEventLoop loop;
    QNetworkReply *replies[6];

    for (int i = 0, i < urls.lenght(); i++){
        replies[i] = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urls[i]));
        connect(replies[i], SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    }
    loop.exec();  // Wait here
    // Rest of code
}
```

Another attempt, perhaps even more nonsensical:

```
void DownloadFiles(QStringList urls)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QEventLoop loops[6];
    QNetworkReply *replies[6];

    for (int i = 0, i < urls.lenght(); i++){
        replies[i] = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urls[i]));
        connect(replies[i], SIGNAL(finished()), &loops[i], SLOT(quit()));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       loops[i]->exec();  // Wait here
    // Rest of code
}
```

Again, my goal is to download multiple file concurrently, and wait for all of them to finish before continuing with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter to check how many times the signal was triggered.

```cpp
#include <QtNetwork>

static void DownloadFiles(const QList<QUrl> & urls){
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QList<QNetworkReply *> replies;
    QEventLoop loop;
    int total = urls.length();
    for(const QUrl & url: urls){
        QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&total, &loop](){
            total--;
            if(total == 0){
                loop.quit();
            }
        });
        replies << reply;
    }
    loop.exec();
    for(QNetworkReply *reply: replies){
        qDebug() << "===============================";
        qDebug() << "url:" << reply->url() << "\nhas error?" << (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError);
        qDebug() << "===============================";
    }
    qDebug() << "Completed";
    qDeleteAll(replies.begin(), replies.end());
    replies.clear();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QList<QUrl> urls { QUrl("https://www.qt.io/"),
                       QUrl("https://github.com/"),
                       QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/") };
    DownloadFiles(urls);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
===============================
url: QUrl("https://www.qt.io/") 
has error? false
===============================
===============================
url: QUrl("https://github.com/") 
has error? false
===============================
===============================
url: QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/") 
has error? false
===============================
Completed
```